# getTeamMapping should get the data from Spring-Data-JPA method or not?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Have a look at the below code

```
teamMappingEntity = (List<TeamMappingEntity>) adminUtilityRequest
    .getTeamMappingRepository()
    .findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted(userEntity, Boolean.FALSE);
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at this line because `getTeamMappingRepository` in `AdminUtilityRequest` class is `null` at this point.
But what I don't understand is if I am calling the Spring-Data-JPA method `findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted` in the above line the data which I get from the Spring Data JPA method should be saved in `getTeamMappingRepository` but it doesn't. WHY????

Although this line works fine.

```
teamMappingEntity =  teamMappingRepository
    .findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeletedFalse(userEntity);
```

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Make yourself a bit clearer.

Comment: @rt.jar Kindly explain the first line of code. concern is "should data from findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted method be copied to getTeamMappingRepository?"

Comment: Nothing will be copied, JPA queries data store to fetch data. And how you are injecting `teamMappingRepository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I am calling the Spring-Data-JPA method `findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted` in the above line the data which I get from the Spring Data JPA method should be saved in `getTeamMappingRepository` but it doesn't.

Nope. 
`findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted` will return some data. 
That's it. 
It won't store it anywhere. 
And certainly not in `getTeamMappingRepository`:

1. That is a method. 
   You can't store anything in a method.
   You would need a field for that.
2. It is of the wrong type. 
   `findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted` returns a `List`, but `getTeamMappingRepository` returns a repository. 
   Two very distinct things.
3. `findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeleted` doesn't contain any information about the existence of `getTeamMappingRepository`.
   There is no way it can manipulate it in any way.

Your real problem is that there is no repository in `adminUtilityRequest`.
We would need to see what you did to get a repository in there.

Possibly you are missing an `@Autowired` annotation, or `adminUtilityRequest` is not a Spring bean so it doesn't get anything injected.

Comment: i directly injected the data in the teamrepository using teamMappingEntity =  teamMappingRepository.findAllByUserEntityAndIsDeletedFalse(userEntity); this works well. You are right return types were different + we can't save anything in method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probally in your `adminUtilityRequest` you need to add `@Autowired` annotation for `"teamMappingRepository"` attribute

If the annotation exist, maybe you object `"adminUtilityRequest"` was built manually outside of Spring context. Should be good you review who this object is created.